# EF4 complex type with navigation property (is it possible) or alternatives?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties, complextype

I hit the wall with doing EF4 Model with DB first approach using Linq-to-Entities with POCO...

I have two tables: `Customer` and `NamePrefix` that are related via `NamePrefixId`. Columns are:

```
Customer             NamePrefix
----------           ----------
CustomerId (PK)      NamePrefixId (PK)
NamePrefixId (FK)
LastName
FirstName
MiddleInitial
....
```

In this instance the `Customer` entity has a navigational property `NamePrefix`.
I created a complex type `NameOfPerson`, so that I can use it in other entities.
The complex type consists of `NamePrefixId`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`.
But now I am getting the following error message on the navigational property to `NamePrefix`:

```
Error 111: There is no property with name 'NamePrefixId' defined in type referred by Role 'Customer'.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described directly in [Complex type help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx). Complex types cannot contain navigation properties.

Comment: Any work-arounds/suggestions, as I am sure I am not the first one to run into this?

Comment: Workaround is not including navigation property in complex type.

Comment: I meant, in lieu of complex types in navigation property, can anyone suggest a better and working approach for what I need to achieve?

Comment: There is not working approach. Simply you can't place navigation property to complex type. You must place it directly to entity `Customer`. If you split Customer table to two entities - `Customer` and `NameOfPerson` you will in turn not be able to reuse `NameOfPerson` entity. No way. If you want to solve it centralize your data about people to single table and create it as entity.

Comment: Well, one (less than ideal but workable) option is to just expose the foreign key column in the complex type, and extend the complex type with a manual navigation property