# Using EF 4.1, can a complex type reference an entity (e.g. in DDD a value object referencing an entity)?

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, value-objects, complextype

[A blog entry](http://stochastyk.blogspot.com/2008/05/value-objects-in-domain-driven-design.html) I read seems to indicate it's ok for value objects to reference entities in domain driven design, and the [follow-up](http://stochastyk.blogspot.com/2008/05/value-objects-in-ddd-part-2-creating.html) explains how to do this in NHibernate.

I would like to do the same thing using Entity Framework 4.1: specifically, have a complex type reference another entity. As an example consider this: I have an entity, let's say, **Invoice** that has a **Total** property of type **Currency**. **Currency** is a complex type containing a property of type `decimal` called **Value** and a **Unit** property of type **CurrencyUnit**. **CurrencyUnit** is a "reference data entity". That is, **CurrencyUnit** in this particular domain is an entity, not a value object itself.

Now while possibly "allowed" in DDD, it's not my preference; I don't want to debate the merits. I'm interested in learning if there is a code-first solution in EF to handle this scenario. I can't seem to find anything, which is odd since complex types map to their entity's containing table, which can of course have foreign key references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crud (no pun intended) I just found this question whose answer indicates its simply not implemented in EF 4.1: [EF4 complex type with navigation property (is it possible) or alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266092)