# Each type name in a schema must be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model with the following structure where I have lists of Codes that can be used within the system.

There is a one to one relationship between a car and an engine so I want the engine details to be mapped to the Car table so an engine is not an entity its just a domain model abstraction. That engine contains a Code that describes the engine Type.

My dbcontext has a DbSet for CodeList and for Car as they are the two aggregate roots in the system. When I attempt to map this to the database I get the following error:

Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'Code' is already defined.

If I remove the Navigation property in the Engine class then the problem goes away but I want to be able to access the Code value without having to look it up independently. If I remove the virtual and attempt to map the id property of the code directly it tells me Code is defined as an entity and may not be redefined as a complex type. I am not sure where I am going wrong with this it seem like a straight forward usage. It looks like Engine is being treated as a Complex Type and therefore cannot have Navigation Properties.

```
CodeList
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Code> codes {get;set;}
}

Code
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}


public Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Engine Engine {get;set;}
}

public Engine 
{
    public int Size {get;set;}
    public int TypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual Code Type {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just having a similar problem when I came across your question.  According to @LadislavMrnka, in EF, a [complex type simply cannot contain a navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616007/ef-4-2-codefirst-navigation-property-within-a-complext-type).  Apparently, however [NHibernate does support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012319/using-ef-4-1-can-a-complex-type-reference-an-entity-e-g-in-ddd-a-value-object).  If sticking with EF, you will have to change your model to accomodate this "feature".  That's what I ended up doing, anyway.

Comment: I was just about to write up a question here and answer it as well.  My initial searching did not find this page which would have saved me time.  Damn complex types!